# href For Image Goes Beyond Image In HTML website with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am making an html website and trying to make the website so when you click the image it takes you to another website. This is the code I have in index.html

```
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
     <div class="metFinLogo"></div>   
 </a>
```

and in css

```css
.metFinLogo{
    background-image: url('./images/metFinLogoImg.png');
    background-size:contain;
    width: 250px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 5%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

When I open index.html the image can still be selected even outside image. I need help to make it so that only clicking where there is image sends to link.
[image: image of error]

Comment: This is because you're not really using an image (`<img>`); you're using the image as a background imagefile on a `<div>`. Since your link/anchor (`<a>`) covers the `<div>`, the entire div is clickable, regardless of where the image ends.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to use a `<a><img /></a>` instead

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` tag is a block level element. It will work if you add `display: inline-block` to .metFinLogo

```
.metFinLogo{
    background-image: url('./images/metFinLogoImg.png');
    background-size:contain;
    width: 250px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 5%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inline-block It’s formatted just like the inline element, where it doesn’t start on a new line. BUT, you can set width and height values.

```
.metFinLogo{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
.metFinLogo{
    background-image: url('https://static.remove.bg/remove-bg-web/6cc620ebfb5922c21227f533a09d892abd65defa/assets/start_remove-c851bdf8d3127a24e2d137a55b1b427378cd17385b01aec6e59d5d4b5f39d2ec.png');
    background-size:contain;
    width: 250px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 5%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
     <div class="metFinLogo"></div>   
 </a>
```